# なんてね interpretation

Tags: translation, nuances

So we have the following situation. There is persons A, B and C. Long ago A and B were friends when according to A B suddenly betrayed her. Now A has been using C for a long while pretending to be a friend in her scheme to get at B. Also according to A, unlike in her case A has been dropping serious hints that she might have something nefaruous going on to C, who has willingly ignored the hints.

Now A is monologuing/talking to unconscious B:

> 悲しい物語は悲しいまま終わるし
>
> 救いの手なんて現れない
>
> ずっと大好きで大切だった子にあっさり裏切られてすべてを失う
>
> …どっちも味わっちゃう**なんてね**
>
> B, あんたはあの時どんな気持ちだったの？

Rough TL:

> Sad tale came to an equally sad end. No help materialized.
>
> Lost everything by simply being betrayed by the girl that I liked and was precious (to me).
>
> ...I experienced both sides of it...as if.
>
> B... What did you feel back then?

Now that bit どっちも味わっちゃう without なんてね works on it's own since A is now betraying C just as (according to A) B betrayed A. But according to a question here, and some other resources なんてね is used to basically say "As if I'd say that" or "Just kidding". I guess A could be saying that situations aren't the same because B never dropped hints to her in her case. Hence me adding that "as if" at the end.

It's just that I'm not sure about that. I feel taking the sentence straight (without) nantene kinda feels better, in which case maybe that nante is just some sort of emphasis. But as I said I'm not sure.

So which reading is more right? What is A trying to say there.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34602/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32711/9831

Comment: So surprise huh. So something like "...who'd have thought I'd expirience both sides (of being betrayed) eh?" would work?